# Inheriting XML files and modifying values

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xslt, xml-parsing

This is a question about **concept**.

I have an **XML** file, let's call it *base*:

```
<base id="default">
    <tags>
        <tag>tag_one</tag>
        <tag>tag_two</tag>
        <tag>tag_three</tag>
    </tags>
    <data>
        <data_a>blue</data_a>
        <data_b>3</data_b>
    </data>
</base>
```

What I want to do is to be able to *extend* this **XML** in another file, modifying individual properties. For example, I want to inherit that file and make a new one with a different **`data/data_a`** node:

```
<base id="green" import="default">
    <data>
        <data_a>green</data_a>
    </data>
</base>
```

So far it's pretty simple, it replaces the old **`data/data_a`** with the new one. I even can add a new node:

```
<base id="ext" import="default">
    <moredata>
        <data>extended version</data>
    </moredata>
</base>
```

And still it's pretty simple. The problem comes when I want to delete a node or deal with XML Lists (like the `tags` node).

How should I reference a particular index on a list? I was thinking doing something like:

```
<base id="diffList" import="default">
    <tags>
        <tag index="1">this is not anymore tag_two</tag>
    </tags>
</base>
```

And for deleting a node / array index:

```
<base id="deleting" import="default">
    <tags>
        <tag index="2"/>
    </tags>
    <data/>
</base>

<!-- This will result in an XML containing these values: -->

<base>
    <tag>tag_one</tag>
    <tag>tag_two</tag>
</base>
```

But I'm not happy with my solutions. I don't know anything about XSLT or other XML transformation tools, but I think someone must have done this before.

The **key** goal I'm looking for is ease to write the XML by hand (both the base and the *"extended"*).

I'm open to new solutions besides XML, if they are easy to write manually.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The below may guide you. XSLT may transform one XML into another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data_a">
        <data_a>green</data_a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tags/tag[1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation of the three templates above:
(1) copy all nodes and attributes
(2) but change data_a node
(3) and do nothing for the first tag element within (any) tags element.

I hope this will help you transforming your XML.